# How to check whether f is a convex and find all stationary points

Tags: optimization

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dESpR.png)

What I attempted was calculating the Hessian and trying to prove that it's positive definite/semi-definite or negative definite/semi-definite. It doesn't seam to work as I am getting that the second order principle minor can be both negative and positive which would suggest that this function is neither convex nor concave.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and write down the problem using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), or, at least, add an `!` right before the image link to make the image appear? See also some [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Furthermore, it would increase the likelihood of getting an useful answer if you were more specific, for instance, writing down in your post the steps you did to solve the problem. Sometimes, we all make small mistakes in the computations. See some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the tips :) I'm quite new here at it seems like the ! command is for those with at least 10 rep. I actually tried writing this problem using MathJax, and did look at the links you've sent before uploading. I literally spend an hour trying to write a function and just gave up.

Comment: Please, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Comment: Formatting tips: $$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1^2 + x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_2^2 + e^{x_3^2}$$ is obtained with `$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1^2 + x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_2^2 + e^{x_3^2}$$`, and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is obtained with `$\mathbb{R}^3$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ertxiem. From now on I will use that. Could you tell me where you can learn all the syntax? it seams like the basic tutorial and quick reference does not have everything.

Comment: Some functions are neither convex nor concave.